# File creation works from localhost but not from mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, rest, cors, phonegap

I am trying to send a file creation request to a remote RESTful API.

Whenever I do this from a local server, it works fine. Whenever I do this from an iOS device, it fails with a CSRF validation failed error. As far as I can tell, that shouldn't happen as it is the exact same code executing on both devices...

This is built using PhoneGap/Cordova. The version of iOS is iOS 11 and the iOS device is an iPhone 8.

Here's the code:

```
    var mathRandom = Math.random();
    var data = {"file": {
            "file": base64,
            "filename": localStorage.username + mathRandom + ".jpg",
            "filepath": "public://" + localStorage.username + mathRandom + ".jpg"
        }
    };
    var result = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: SITE_URL + "/" + ENDPOINT + '/file.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            moduleDebugger('account', errorThrown, "FILE SAVE ERROR");
            return 'null';
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            moduleDebugger('account', data, 'success');

        }
    });
```

(Yes, I know it is async, but this block of code absolutely MUST execute before anything after it - I am fine with the UX degradation)

I am using the same user, permissions are currently set so that ANYONE should be able to create files, even anonymously (for testing).

My CORS settings are these:

```
Internal path
Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Use <mirror> to echo back the Origin header.
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

*|<mirror>|GET, PUT, POST, DELETE|Content-Type, Authorization, X-CSRF-Token|true
```

What would prevent a mobile user from saving a file, but not a user from localhost? Note, the server where the file will be saved is remote to both of these devices.

This is the error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed)

I am also getting the error:

> Failed to load resource: Data URL Decoding Failed

But I am unsure if it is related to the above error - it comes a while after this error occurs. I have been unable to pinpoint what is causing it to occur.

EDIT: Even a static base64 string that I've tested repeatedly on localhost doesn't work.

Comment: What is the backend framework that you are using?

Comment: Drupal 7, I'll probably change the backend framework at some point, but this is an old project I'm trying to finish up.